# How to calculate no. of binary strings containg substring "00"?

Tags: c, string, binary

I need to calculate no of possible substrings containing "00" as a substring.
I know the length of the binary string.

Eg: for a string of length 4, possible substrings are:
0000
0001
0010
0011
0100
1000
1001
1100

I just need the number of possible combinations, not enumerate all of them

PS: max length 10^6

Comment: Have you tried anything? What happened? Why didn't it work? Post some code and example results.

Comment: I'd calculate the number that DON'T have it as a possible substring, and then subtract it from total number of strings.

Comment: @Jim - a slightly better method would be counting the number of legs of these aforesaid substrings, and dividing by #num_legs

Comment: This is a math problem, often related to coin flipping. Perhaps this will help: http://openstudy.com/updates/4eac3aabe4b0f28a15fb9b9d

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about math. Should be on math.stackexchange.com

Comment: @Michelle method is what I am looking for, code is the next step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is calculated using fibonacci n-step number sequences.

The number of string permutations containing k 0's from a string of length n is 2^n-fibk( n + 2 ).

In your case you have k=2 so you use the normal fibonacci sequence giving you the solution to your example with a string length of n=4: 2^4 - fib( 6 )= 16 - 8 = 8.

EDIT: See here: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Fibonaccin-StepNumber.html

Answer (score 0):

I think I can give you an idea for an algorithm:

Let `count(n)` be the the the number of possible substrings containing "00" for a string o length `n`.

We now examine strings `s(n)` of size `n` (n > 3). Let `c[i]` be it's digits (1 <= i <= n) and `s(j)` the substrings of the first `j` digits (i <= j < n).

1. If `s(n-1)` already contains "00" then `s(n)` also contains "00" no matter if `c[n]` is "0" or "1". So we already have `2 * count(n-1)` strings that match the condition.
2. if `s(n-1)` doesn't contain "00", but `s(n)` does, then `s(n-1)` must end with "0" (thus `c[n-1]` must be "0") and `c[n]` must be "0". Because of `c[n-1] = "0"`, `c[n-2]`
   must be "1" (otherwise `s(n-1)` would end with "00"). So we know that `s(n-1)` ends with "10". `s(n-3)` (the substring before that "10"!) can be any string that doesn't contain "00", and there are `2^(n-3) - count(n-3)` of them.

Adding both, we get `count(n) = 2*count(n-1) + 2^(n-3) - count(n-3)`

We know that count(1) = 0 (because the string is too short), count(2) = 1 (00) and count(3) = 3 (000, 001, 100). So we can start an iteration, and let's try for n=4 (where you already have the result):

`count(4) = 2*count(3) +2^1 - count(1) = 2*3 + 2 - 0 = 8`